# How to use StartsWith with an array of string?

Tags: linq

Suppose I have an array of strings:

```
var array = new string[] {"A", "B"}.
```

Then I want check if the following string: "boca" starts with the letter included in the array.

What I did is:

```
var result = "boca".StartsWith(array);
```

but the method doesn't not accept an arra as argument but a single string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to loop the array and check if the word starts with anything in the array. Something like this:

```
var result = array.Any(s => "boca".StartsWith(s));
```

Assuming your `array` is `{"A", "B"}`, then `result` will be `false`, because `StartsWith` is case-sensitive by default.

If you want it case-insensitive, then this will work:

```
var result = array.Any(s => "boca".StartsWith(s, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
```

In this case, `result` will be `true`.

Comment: Thanks, but could you explain better the `CultureIgnoreCase`? For example, if the string startswith: "a" and the array contains "A", which result will be returned?

Comment: I updated my answer to show what `result` would be in each case.